# ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, platformio

How can I make the [WifiManager library](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager) work on a ESP32 board? I'm using PlatformIO to develop my code.

Here are my imports:

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

WiFiManager wifiManager;
```

platformio.ini

```
[env:esp32cam]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32cam
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
build_flags = -DMQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE=36000
lib_deps = 
    espressif/esp32-camera@^1.0.0
    knolleary/PubSubClient@^2.8
    bblanchon/ArduinoJson@^6.18.5
    tzapu/WiFiManager@^0.16.0
```

But when I run the code, I get this following error:

```
.pio\libdeps\esp32cam\WiFiManager/WiFiManager.h:16:25: fatal error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory
```

After further research, I see that WiFiManager uses ESP8266WiFi.h and now I'm wondering how I can make this library work on my ESP32 or is there an alternative library? The project's readme does say it works on ESP32.

Comment: And how does your platformio.ini look like?

Comment: @gre_gor Updated my question

Comment: Add `#include <ESP8266.h>`.

Comment: @hcheung tried it before, it won't work even with that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The latest release of WiFiManager library (0.16) is almost a year old and doesn't support ESP32.
You will need to install the library from Github to get ESP32 support.

In your platformio.ini replace

```
tzapu/WiFiManager@^0.16.0
```

with

```
https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager.git@^2.0.5-beta
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I completely overlooked the version, thank you very much! Greatly appreciate it

Comment: On PlatformIO, the latest version available is v0.16.0, https://registry.platformio.org/libraries/tzapu/WiFiManager which lacks support for the ESP32